# one Dimensional gauss convolution function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gaussian

I am trying to write a function that returns a one dimentional gauss filter. the function took sigma as a parameter. The problem is that the function returns the same array for all sigmas.

```
  function gaussFilter=gauss(sigma)  
  width = 3 * sigma;  
  support = (-width :sigma: width);  
  gaussFilter= exp( - (support).^2 / (2*sigma^2));   
  gaussFilter = gaussFilter/ sum(gaussFilter);
```

Note that support array is calculated correctly but the problem arise when applying the exp.

Comment: what happens when you execute the `exp` with a scalar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is that the filter needs to be wide enough to represent the Gaussian function. The rule of thumb is to use filter size of at least `6*sigma`.

Since the support needs to be centered around zero, that would give you the range of `-3*sigma` to `+3*sigma` (to be more accurate, it is `-/+ round(6*sigma - 1)/2` to account for the zero in the middle). Hence:

```
function gaussFilter = gauss(sigma)
    width = round((6*sigma - 1)/2);
    support = (-width:width);
    gaussFilter = exp( -(support).^2 ./ (2*sigma^2) );
    gaussFilter = gaussFilter/ sum(gaussFilter);
```

**Example**: (all the following are equivalent)

```
sigma = 1.2;
width = round((6*sigma - 1)/2);

gauss(sigma)

normpdf( -width:width, 0, sigma )

fspecial('gaussian', [1 2*width+1], sigma)

h = gausswin(2*width+1)';
h = h / sum(h)
```

Comment: +1 back (I actually +1'ed this a long time ago!)  Very nice if you don't have the Image Processing Toolbox.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with the results. Your `support` vector is essentially,

```
[-3*sigma -2*sigma -1*sigma 0 1*sigma 2*sigma 3*sigma]
```

And if you square each element of support and multiply by -1, `-support.^2`

```
[-9*sigma^2 -4*sigma^2 -1*sigma^2 0 -1*sigma^2 -4*sigma^2 -9*sigma^2]
```

So dividing it by `2*sigma^2` will always result in the same vector,

```
[-9/2 -4/2 -1/2 0 -1/2 -4/2 -9/2]
```

Or

```
-4.5000   -2.0000   -0.5000         0   -0.5000   -2.0000   -4.5000
```

So **that's why you always get the same answer.**

So you need to check your **algorithm** for making a one-dimensional gaussian filter.

**EDIT:**

Your original code is fine: **except** I don't  understand why you've made `support` with `-3*sigma:sigma:3*sigma` - you should change it to `support = -3:3`.

You can also use:

```
gaussFilter = fspecial('gaussian',[1 7],sigma)
```

**EDIT:** Check out [Amro's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833082/one-dimensional-gauss-convolution-function-in-matlab/1835663#1835663) for the full code and explanation why `support = -3*sigma:3*sigma` and not `support = -3*sigma:sigma:3*sigma`

Comment: Thanks very much,but i dont want to apply for loop. I would like to use a vector (support) instead.Please could you tell me how to do it.

Comment: What you wrote is correct for sigma=1,but 3*sigma:sigma:3*sigma will give me six elements with sigma between each two.thanks for fspecial advice but i dont want to use a built in one.But even with support=-3:3 the results will be the same, wont it?

Comment: The results will change with respect to sigma. `support` should be independent of `sigma`, it should only depend on the window size, which in your case seems to be a 1x7 vector.

Comment: I am sorry for my heavy questions, but could you please correct my code and give me the whole correct one depending on my code..I am so sorry again.

Comment: Are there any other questions?