# How to add a Gaussian shaped object to an image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am interested in adding a single Gaussian shaped object to an existing image, something like in the attached image.  The base image that I would like to add the object to is 8-bit unsigned with values ranging from 0-255.  The bright object in the attached image is actually a tree represented by normalized difference vegetation index (NDVI) data.  The attached script is what I have have so far.  How can I add a a Gaussian shaped abject (i.e. a tree) with values ranging from 110-155 to an existing NDVI image?

[**Sample data available here**](ftp://ftp.agrc.utah.gov/Imagery/NAIP2011_4-band/) which can be used with this script to calculate NDVI

[image]

---

```
file = 'F:\path\to\fourband\image.tif';
[I R] = geotiffread(file);
outputdir = 'F:\path\to\output\directory\'

%% Make NDVI calculations
NIR = im2single(I(:,:,4));
red = im2single(I(:,:,1));
ndvi = (NIR - red) ./ (NIR + red);
ndvi = double(ndvi);

%% Stretch NDVI to 0-255 and convert to 8-bit unsigned integer
ndvi = floor((ndvi + 1) * 128); % [-1 1] -> [0 256]
ndvi(ndvi < 0) = 0;             % not really necessary, just in case & for symmetry
ndvi(ndvi > 255) = 255;         % in case the original value was exactly 1
ndvi = uint8(ndvi);             % change data type from double to uint8

%% Need to add a random tree in the image here


%% Write to geotiff
tiffdata = geotiffinfo(file);
outfilename = [outputdir 'ndvi_' '.tif'];  
geotiffwrite(outfilename, ndvi, R, 'GeoKeyDirectoryTag', tiffdata.GeoTIFFTags.GeoKeyDirectoryTag)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your post is asking how to do three things:

1. How do we generate a Gaussian shaped object?
2. How can we do this so that the values range between 110 - 155?
3. How do we place this in our image?

Let's answer each one separately, where the order of each question builds on the knowledge from the previous questions.

## How do we generate a Gaussian shaped object?

You can use `fspecial` from the Image Processing Toolbox to generate a Gaussian for you:

```
mask = fspecial('gaussian', hsize, sigma);
```

`hsize` specifies the size of your Gaussian.  You have not specified it here in your question, so I'm assuming you will want to play around with this yourself.  This will produce a `hsize x hsize` Gaussian matrix.  `sigma` is the standard deviation of your Gaussian distribution.  Again, you have also not specified what this is.  `sigma` and `hsize` go hand-in-hand.  Referring to my [previous post on how to determine `sigma`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832852/by-which-measures-should-i-set-the-size-of-my-gaussian-filter-in-matlab), it is generally a good rule to set the standard deviation of your mask to be set to the **3-sigma** rule.  As such, once you set `hsize`, you can calculate `sigma` to be:

```
sigma = (hsize-1) / 6;
```

As such, figure out what `hsize` is, then calculate your `sigma`.  After, invoke `fspecial` like I did above.  It's generally a good idea to make `hsize` an **odd** integer.  The reason why is because when we finally place this in your image, the syntax to do this will allow your mask to be symmetrically placed.  I'll talk about this when we get to the last question.

## How can we do this so that the values range between 110 - 155?

We can do this by adjusting the values within `mask` so that the minimum is 110 while the maximum is 155.  This can be done by:

```
%// Adjust so that values are between 0 and 1
maskAdjust = (mask - min(mask(:))) / (max(mask(:)) - min(mask(:)));

%//Scale by 45 so the range goes between 0 and 45
%//Cast to uint8 to make this compatible for your image
maskAdjust = uint8(45*maskAdjust);

%// Add 110 to every value to range goes between 110 - 155
maskAdjust = maskAdjust + 110;
```

In general, if you want to adjust the values within your Gaussian mask so that it goes from `[a,b]`, you would normalize between 0 and 1 first, then do:

```
maskAdjust = uint8((b-a)*maskAdjust) + a;
```

You'll notice that we cast this mask to `uint8`.  The reason we do this is to make the mask compatible to be placed in your image.

## How do we place this in our image?

All you have to do is figure out the row and column you would like the **centre** of the Gaussian mask to be placed.  Let's assume these variables are stored in `row` and `col`.  As such, assuming you want to place this in `ndvi`, all you have to do is the following:

```
hsizeHalf = floor(hsize/2); %// hsize being odd is important
%// Place Gaussian shape in our image
ndvi(row - hsizeHalf : row + hsizeHalf, col - hsizeHalf : col + hsizeHalf) = maskAdjust;
```

The reason why `hsize` should be odd is to allow an even placement of the shape in the image.  For example, if the mask size is 5 x 5, then the above syntax for `ndvi` simplifies to:

```
ndvi(row-2:row+2, col-2:col+2) = maskAdjust;
```

From the centre of the mask, it stretches 2 rows above and 2 rows below.  The columns stretch from 2 columns to the left to 2 columns to the right.  If the mask size was even, then we would have an ambiguous choice on how we should place the mask.  If the mask size was 4 x 4 as an example, should we choose the second row, or third row as the centre axis?  As such, to simplify things, make sure that the size of your mask is odd, or `mod(hsize,2) == 1`.

This should hopefully and adequately answer your questions.  Good luck!

Comment: +1 nice answer. Here are some more ways to build the Gaussian filter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1835663/97160 (note that it is a [separable filter](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/04/separable-convolution/), so we can get the 2D filter from the 1D one)