# Normalizing by dividing by max value VS sum of all values

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, normalization

I'm implementing a Gaussian filter in which, as explained in [one Dimensional gauss convolution function in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833082/one-dimensional-gauss-convolution-function-in-matlab), I'm normalising the filter coefficients by dividing them by sum of all the coefficients.   [Normalizing by max value or by total value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638464/normalizing-by-max-value-or-by-total-value) explains that normalisation can be done by dividing by maximum of the coefficients too.

I'm unable to get the point that what should be the conditions/specifications to be considered in choosing the normalising factor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conventionally, you should divide by the *sum* of all the coefficients, so that the DC gain is unity (i.e. low frequency signals are not changed by the filter).

Comment: and when should it be divided by maximum value?

Comment: I can't think of a reason to divide by the maximum. [There exist some fixed-point systems that can most easily mutiply by numbers in the range [-1..1) and on those you might scale the largest coefficient magnitude to unity, for precision. But that doesn't apply in Matlab, which uses floating-point.]